# Monoidal version of profunctors/distributors

Tags: category-theory, profunctors

The usual definition for a Profunctor / Distributor is a functor in $Cat$

$$B^{op} \times A \to Set $$

So that it's adjunct to
$$A \to Set^{B^{op}} $$

Have generalisation

$$ B^{op} \otimes A \to Set$$
to an arbitrary monoidal product been fruitfully studied ?

Comment: In order for the generalisation to exist, you have to consider profunctors with respect to another monoidal (closed?) structure on $Cat$; there are not that many. The [funny](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/funny+tensor+product) one does not give an interesting notion of profunctor for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @Berci yes of course, A^op. fixing the question